# How to subscribe hark_msgs types

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am using ROS Hydro in ubuntu 12.04. and I want to create a subscriber of hark_msgs. whenever I run a simple publisher designed in HARK from batchflow, I am able to view the messages in the terminal (using rostopic echo). When I am trying to  create a subscriber ,I get this message:

```
Could not find a configuration file for package hark_msgs.

Set hark_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
for hark_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

hark_msgsConfig.cmake
hark_msgs-config.cmake
```

(whenever I include hark_msgs in the dependencies, I get the above error.)

I found the folder where hark_msg related (.msg) files are but .cmake files are no where to be seen. Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173905/how-to-subscribe-hark_msgs-types./) by [keshav_sarraf](https://answers.ros.org/users/18286/keshav_sarraf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2014-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a rosbuild package to subscribe hark_msgs and it worked.

---

Originally posted by [keshav_sarraf](https://answers.ros.org/users/18286/keshav_sarraf/) with karma: 66 on 2014-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

<del>Have you declared a dependency on `hark_msgs` in both your `CMakeLists.txt` and your `package.xml`? catkin needs that information to properly setup your include path(s).</del>

<del>See the *Resolving dependencies* section on the [How to do common tasks](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/index.html) page of the catkin documentation.</del>

---

Edit: on second thought, the fact that you get that error message indicates that you are declaring a dependency, but that catkin / CMake cannot resolve it.

You say you "found the folder where hark_msg related (.msg) files are". Can you make sure that the package is on your package path? Does this work: `rospack find hark_msgs`?

--

Edit2: as far as I can tell `hark_msgs` is not a catkin package (ie: it is a 'dry' package), while your own package *is* a catkin package (ie: 'wet'). Wet packages cannot depend on dry packages, see [Overlaying Dry and Wet Workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild#Overlaying_Dry_and_Wet_Workspaces), which is why you are getting the error about catkin not being able to find the `hark_msgs` configuration file.

There is probably a `manifest.xml` file in the `hark_msgs` directory. Hydro should still be able to build dry packages (with `rosbuild`), so if you create a rosbuild package you should be able to use the hark stacks.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-06-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [keshav_sarraf](https://answers.ros.org/users/18286/keshav_sarraf/) on 2014-06-18**:
let me try converting it to catkin_package.